# PowerBI: SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR function not working

Tags: powerbi

I am getting the following error message when I write the below code:
Value for 'Total Sales'cannot is determined. Either 'Total Sales' does not exist or there is no current row for a column named 'Total Sales'

```
enter code here
```

LYSales = CALCULATE([Total Sales],SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date]))

How do I fix this? I have the Total Sales column with data. It is set to general currency.

[image]

Comment: precede the column with the table name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Written in this way your formula is not referencing a measure, not a column, also you will need an expression inside calculate.

```
-- This reference a Measure, which in your case is not defined
LYSales = CALCULATE([Total Sales],SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date]))
-- you can create it with this formula
Total Sales = SUM('_TableName_'[Total Sales])

--The other way is to use only one formula
LYSales = CALCULATE(SUM('_TableName_'[Total Sales]),SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date]))
```

As a note, to use time intelligence functions you need to mark the calendar table as "date table": right click on the table -> "Mark as Date Table"

Comment: LYSales = CALCULATE(sum('Sales'[Total Sales]),SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date])) works... thank you. Seems measure do not lead to a new column. I do not have a new column LYSales.

Comment: I didn't understand that you wanted a calculated column (which will have a static value), usually, this kind of calculation is made using measures, but that's up to the requirements. This DAX code should work also for a calculated column.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation looks at the table column as a whole. Your formula uses the value in the current row of the column. So, change it to

```
LYSales = CALCULATE('Your Table Name'[Total Sales],SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date]))
```